# How to define types with user defined attributes

Tags: modelica

This modelica code gives in error:

```
type myReal
  extends Real;
  parameter RealType myAttribute;
  
end myReal;
```

But how to define types with user defined attributes else?

Comment: Welcome Kilian, it has been awhile! 
Can you explain your underlying use-case in more detail?

Comment: Hi Hans, thank you for the quick reply. For optimization applications we considered to add more attributes to variables to store information that we now handle disconnected to the model variables. E.g. the value of a state in the last iteration (t-1) of an estimator.

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible in the current Modelica tools without changing the compiler. In OpenModelica we have added new attributes to types for example when handling Uncertainty but one needs to basically propagate these through the compiler depending on what they want to achieve with them. The Modelica spec currently doesn't allow adding new things to the basic types. You could use annotations instead as these are usually propagated by default but you will still need to change the compiler or the runtime system to handle them.

Comment: Thank you Adrian. It is a pity that Modelica is quite inflexible with that respect. Maybe we give it a try to use records or models instead. But that will require a lot of modeling effort compared to creating a new type and using it.